# How can I setup an EVENT into phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, scheduled-tasks

I cannot understand two things of EVENT's box:

[image]

As I specified them *(by red square)*, I'm trying to understand:

- What's the difference between `RECURRING` and `ONE TIME`?
- What happens when I mark that check-box as checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recurring [event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) is one which executes repeatedly, once at `start-time` and once every `interval` thereafter. A one-time event is one which will execute only once, at `start-time`.

The scheduler stores event definitions in an **Events** table where they can be seen with the `SHOW EVENTS` command; each `CREATE EVENT` inserts a new record into this table. Normal system behaviour is that once a one-time event has passed, or a recurring event's `end-time` has passed, the event will be deleted from the table. There may be occasions, however, when one wishes to retain a record of past events, for example for review, or so that a particularly complex event can be rerun with `ALTER EVENT` instead of retyping the entire event definition. The checkbox belongs to the label **On completion preserve**. This controls whether the event definition is deleted from the events table once it has completed, or kept. The default behaviour is to delete; checking this box causes the event to be preserved.

Comment: Thanks +1 .. I figured the first one out. But still I don't know what that check-box does *(look, I don't know English very well, so may you please explain it by simple words `:-)`)*

Comment: I've added a more-detailed description.

Comment: I see. thanks again. And my last question, what's [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ayh6S.png) ?

Comment: That has to do with replication, about which I know very little, except that in one replication scheme you have one **master** server whose data is updated directly by clients, and one or more **slave** servers which clients can query but which are only updated by the master. At a guess, I would think that `SLAVESIDE_DISABLED` means that an event should only execute on the master server instead of being pushed out to execute on the slaves as well.

Comment: Oh just one thing, can I create an event without end time? *(expire time)*, I mean is that possible to I create an even which works forever?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Just by not defining `ENDS ..` ?

Comment: Yes. You can also omit `STARTS` to have the event execute immediately, and you can use `ENDS` without `STARTS`.